# Stop tableview auto scroll when reload

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

My problem is when I click on plus or minus I reload to tableview that is okay but when it reload it is automatically scroll and also my section header is blink. I have attached [clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntkdnqta0sgfbwk/Bug.mov?dl=0) for more clearance.

And I used this code for reload tableview

```
let contentOffset = tblItemList.contentOffset
tblItemList.reloadData()
tblItemList.layoutIfNeeded()
tblItemList.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```

Added

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

    if arrCategoryList.count > 0 {
        let data = (arrCategoryList[indexPath.section].product_list ?? [])[indexPath.row]
        cell.setItemData(data)

        if data.is_added {
            cell.btnAdd.isHidden = true
            cell.lblQuantity.text = "\(data.product_quantity)"
        }
        else {
            cell.btnAdd.isHidden = false
        }

        cell.btnMinus.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnPlus.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnAdd.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickAdd), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.btnPlus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickPlus), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.btnMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickMinus), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `cellForRowAt` logic? Also i think `reloadData` is more than enough to refresh the data. if your height calculation/estimation is correct, you shouldn't need the last two lines.

Comment: Try to remove `tblItemList.layoutIfNeeded()` and see if it's the reason of the issue or not. Additionally, is there a need for `tblItemList.layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: @Cerlin Please check I added cell for row

Comment: @AhmadF let me try this

Comment: I tried with removed tblItemList.layoutIfNeeded() but not working. It will scroll down my tableview @AhmadF

Comment: have you tired tableview.beginupdate and endupdate ?

Answer (score -2):

You are reloading whole tableView for updating a single cell. Just use **tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: //row goes here, section: //section goes here)], with: .automatic)**
and header blinks may be because you using UItableViewCell as header view. Just use UITableHeaderFooterView with the help of XIB and register it as HeaderView in your tableView.[Just see this for header](http://ios-tutorial.com/custom-header-view-xib-uitableview/)

Comment: Thanks for help. But UITableHeaderFooterView this is deprecated.

Comment: hi kamlesh just check it out man. its available from ios-6 and available till latest update. May be you are living in future and you saw it deprecated there :D